# change nimbus thumb slider to arrow shape

Tags: java, slider, jslider, nimbus

How Can I use the default arrow shape of thump slider in nimbus?

I set the nimbus L&F and my thumb shape is a circle like this  [image]
, but I'd like a triangle like this [image].
how can I change it or change back to it's default (that is, without nimbus just for slider thumb shape).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer:

```
JSlider slider = new JSlider();
slider.putClientProperty( "Slider.paintThumbArrowShape", Boolean.TRUE );
```